# how to put 3 buttons at the bottom of web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I was able to put only one button but now I want to add more 2 buttons at the left of first one.

I tried but all the buttons appeared on the same position "bottom right" as I am using blogger so I have to put HTML and CSS code on the same page.

```css
#ul_top_hypers li {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  max-width: 35%;
  max-height: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_top_hypers">
  <li><a class="unused" href="tel:01027884476"><img src="img 1" /></a></li>
  <li><a class="unused" href="https://m.me/baha2.IT"><img src="img 2" /></a></li>
  <li><a class="unused" href="https://wa.me/201027884476"><img src="img 3" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

This my website if that helps: [here](https://www.experts-ksa.com/2019/10/Carpenter-Medina.html).

Comment: you are fixing all buttons on same position... instead do this... do position:fixed on your ul_top_hypers.... and then have your ul li display:inline-block and tadaa... :D

Comment: Change your css to remove the `li`. It appears you want the whole `ul` fixed to the bottom. Your code currently targets each `li` element and because of that, they will all be in the same spot. Just do `#ul_top_hypers {`

Answer (score 0):

As the default template used `FIXED` position for that button, I suggest remove `FIXED` position from `li` and get it to the `ul` instead.

```css
#ul_top_hypers{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

#ul_top_hypers li{
display: inline;
max-width:35%;
max-height:35%;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_top_hypers">
<li><a class="unused" href="tel:01027884476"> <img src="img 1"> </a></li>

<li><a class="unused" href="https://m.me/baha2.IT"> <img src="img 2"> </a></li>

<li><a class="unused" href="https://wa.me/201027884476"> <img src="img 3"> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time remember that what we want to do and what we miss. Check your code that "ul" is our main set and "li" is our subset. When you fixed position for subset it will arrange all subset in single position because their right/left/bottom/top position is same. So we have to fixed position for our main set not sub set.

Update code will be like this one.

```
    #ul_top_hypers {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }

    #ul_top_hypers li {
      display: inline;
      max-width: 35%;
      max-height: 35%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
      <li><a class="unused" href="tel:01027884476"><img src="img 1" /></a></li>
      <li><a class="unused" href="https://m.me/baha2.IT"><img src="img 2" /></a></li>
      <li><a class="unused" href="https://wa.me/201027884476"><img src="img 3" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```